# Get documents where id is 'ID1' OR 'ID2'

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm asking to ES for documents that `id` is one or another:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "should" : [ {
        "term" : {
          "id" : "9a2646d4-e124-11e5-a976-382c4ab9e433"
        }
      }, {
        "term" : {
          "id" : "d7bf6f3b-27c0-11e6-b2ce-382c4ab9e433"
        }
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

These documents with these `id` exist in ES index.

Shortly, I want to get whichever document that its `id == 'x' OR id == 'y'`.

What am I doint wrong?

Comment: The `id` field is analyzed or not_analyzed? If analyzed then what analyzer it's using?

Comment: With `id` I mean the identifier field created by ES in order to save the documents. I don't know which is the analyzer assigned to it by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ids` query for that:

```
GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "ids": {
      "values": [
        "9a2646d4-e124-11e5-a976-382c4ab9e433",
        "d7bf6f3b-27c0-11e6-b2ce-382c4ab9e433"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it not possible to use `search API`? I would need to get documents with `id = X and field = Y`. Can I build a query using both ones?

Comment: **It is** the search API. And yes you can combine that query with others.

Comment: @Jordi this answer is correct for your initial question.